# Create parameterized URL for my Search box

Tags: javascript, url, node.js, express

I have a single html page , which displays all the content  ( by all the content i mean  , form submits , main page , form results .. etc . a lot of DOM manipulations ) Its fully ajax based. The problem i am facing is ,   I have a search box  where the user inputs a job_id and all the information regarding the job gets displayed , All under the same url

www.hostname.com/index.html

But what i need is , when the user searches for the job_id , my url should be something like

www.hostname.com/index.html?jobid='abcd'

so that users can bookmark this url and can get the info , by just going to the link. 
I just have one html page (index.html) and i intend  to keep it that way. How will i go about doing this ?
such that , if the user enters  www.hostname.com/index.html he goes to the index.page with default looks and if he enters  www.hostname.com/index.html?jobid='abcd' only the output for the jobid is shown.

PS: i am using expressJS

Comment: Check on load if there is a parameter in the url and react on it. If `jobid` is found, fill the form and submit it (or set of the ajax request).

Comment: so basically i have to handle this in the client side ? , where i parse the url . Hm . thats good , but suppose if i put this form in a iframe ,will the client side parsing still work ? because , window.location will be pointing to something else .

Comment: Server-side is the better choice but i thought of the _fully ajax based_ that you wan't a client side solution. Your infos aren't that satisfying ;)

Comment: srry for not mentioning iframe . Well currently it aint necessary as of now , but its definitely in the roadmap. coming back to the point , how will i go about doing this in the server side , given that i use ExpressJS. i already have routing rules for '/' and '/index' .

Comment: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#req.param()

Answer (score 0):

A simple and backwards compatible solution is to use `location.hash` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)) to save your parameters. Some applications like URL shorteners will remove the hash.

For modern browsers you should look into [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) which allows you to actually change the URL.

Comment: i did think of window.location , but will it become a problem , if put this form in a iframe ?  Also , is pushState supported in all the mordern browsers , and will it be problem if i use iframe ?

Comment: @Rahul it won't work from an iframe. Why don't you do it all via XHR instead? You can also set the `target` attribute on a form to an iframe, which then communicates with the root page (pointless though if you can do that with ajax).